# Store updated credentials for an Access linked table

Tags: microsoft-access, windows-authentication

FYI: I am running Access 2010, but the file is saved using "Access 2002 - 2003 file format, if relevant.

I have an Access database containing a linked table that was created using Windows Authentication (I think).

However, I connect to it using a username and password instead.  This means that to open it, I have to double click it, wait for it to realise the stored credentials are not working, show me an error (Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.), and then provide the dialogue box where I can actually enter the password so the table opens.

I don't mind entering the password each time, but it would be nice to sidestep receiving the "Connection failed" error every time.  Is it possible to change the settings of the linked table so that it doesn't think it's a Windows Authentication connection any more and just jumps straight to "Please give me the password"?  I don't know how the table was created, so I can't rebuild it myself from scratch.

Comment: Is this connecting to a SQL database? You may have to delete the linked table and recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

Linked table manager: check the "Always prompt for new location" and that should allow you to update the username associated with the link